# Building a DataTable to a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, custom-controls

Are there any tutorials around for how one would go about creating a control that can be bound to a DataSet? I can't seem to find anything much about it on Google.

I've tried this, where my control has a DataRowCollection property called Items (and a dataset called ds, containing a single table):

```
ctrl.DataBindings.Add("Items", ds.Tables[0], "Rows");
```

But I get an ArgumentException:
Cannot bind to the property or column Rows on the DataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this will help: [Data Binding in .NET / C# Windows Forms](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html).